# CloudFormationでLambdaを追加するための、S3バケット作成からTemplateに反映までの作業を一括で実現する方法はないでしょうか？

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

CloudFormationでlambdaのファンクションを追加するためのリソースを作りたいと考えています。

### 聞きたい事

cloudFormationのテンプレートで、lambdaに必要な作業を1つのテンプレートにまとめて書くことはできませんか？

### 状況

CloudFormationの「AWS::Lambda::Function」で使うソースを指定する場合は、次の方法があります。

1. s3バケットにソースをアップして、Code属性にそのバケットの情報を追記する
2. CloudFormtaionに直接スクリプトを書いてしまう。

今回は、jsのライブラリを組み合わせて使うので、前者の方法で実装します。 
この場合、バケット作成->lambdaのアップロード->スタック作成の順番で実施する必要があります。  
私の調べる限り、CloudFormationでは、この3つの作業を1つのテンプレートに入れることは出来なさそうです。

`aws cloudformation package`で、s3のパスを指定した状態のテンプレートを生成（コンパイル？）する事ができる様ですが、バケットの作成までは自動化出来ないです。

### テンプレート化したい一連の作業の詳細

下記の作業をCloudFormationのテンプレートに書いて、実行時に全て実行する。

- 任意のS3バケットを作成する
- 作成したS3バケットに対してLambdaのソースコードをアップロードする
- CloudFormationのテンプレートのCodeプロパティに上記の情報を適用する。  
  具体的にはResouceのPropertiesに下記を追加したいです。

  ```
  "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": <1.で作成したbucket名>,
      "S3Key": "<2.でアップロードしたファイル名>"
  }
  ```

#### イメージ

[image: 構成イメージ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAMと`aws cloudformation package`を使うのが良いと思います。

例えば、下記の`template.yaml`の`CodeUri`のようにファイルのパスを指定します。

```
$ grep Uri template.yaml
      CodeUri: LambdaFunctionOverHttps.py
$ ls LambdaFunctionOverHttps.py 
LambdaFunctionOverHttps.py
$
```

`aws cloudformation package`で`template.yaml`とS3バケットを指定すると、

1. lambda関数をS3バケットにアップロード
2. `template.yaml`の`CodeUri`をS3バケットにアップロードしたS3パスに修正したcloudformationのテンプレートを出力

してくれます。

```
$ aws cloudformation package --template template.yaml --s3-bucket lambda-zipfile > packaged-template.yaml
$ grep CodeUri packaged-template.yaml 
      CodeUri: s3://lambda-zipfile/7a1fd29b27ea23ac1cc381189182062b
$ aws s3 ls s3://lambda-zipfile/7a1fd29b27ea23ac1cc381189182062b
2018-04-19 19:17:19        640 7a1fd29b27ea23ac1cc381189182062b
```

出力されたテンプレートを`aws cloudformation deploy`すればlambda関数が作成されます。